# No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered? in Spring 4 MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have the typical application Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration (Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven integration ).

Here my class:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

The content above resembles the content of web.xml as we are using the front-controller DispatherServler, assigning the mapping (url-pattern in xml) and instead of providing the path to spring configuration file(spring-servlet.xml) , here we are registering the Configuration Class.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've upload the same war to another tomcat 7 and it works !  and in my tomcat other applications like http://localhost:8080/examples/ works well, as well. Strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = null;
    webApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webApplicationContext.setConfigLocation("//write the package name pointing to configuration classes 
like webApplicationConfig and RootWebApplicationConfig classes//");

    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = null;
    dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(webApplicationContext);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);
    servlet.addMapping("*.mvc");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(2);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I just explain how to do this using custom class and implement interface.
I try my best to solve this question,i have only five month experience in spring-mvc and not done this custom spring servlet mapping in practicle.
I hope my post is help you.

Maven configuration:**Add** any spring mvc version **dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Custom **Initializer** class

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("eu.kielczewski.example.config");
        return context;
    }
```

**Configuration** classes

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "eu.kielczewski.example")
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error happening when there is a JAR dependencies problem or a lack of dependencies. If you are in Eclipse sometimes I lose my Maven dependencies. You can check this by doing right click in the project, go to Deployment Assembly and make sure that Maven Dependencies is there. If not click Add and select Maven Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ContextLoaderListener to your ServletContext, here:

```
conteiner.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
```